# Aws EC2 instance : Change type restricted

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, changetype

I've got 2 t2.large instances which need to be upgrade to t2.xlarge. Problem is that t2.* is not available in the change type drop-list!

I created another instance - like the first one - , I can update to t2.xlarge.
I added 2 EBS disk - like the first one -, I can update to t2.xlarge.

Any idea of what can limits the list of available type of instance in the drop-list?!

Comment: It could be that the underlying host does not support t2.xlarge or has insufficient capacity to launch t2.xlarge instance.

Comment: What _is_ displayed in the Instance Type drop-down list? Is it empty? Does it only show some values? Can you show us a picture? This sounds _very_ unusual. While the AMI type could restrict which families are available, it should always offer a choice within the same family.

Comment: @krishna_mee2004 Each host only runs one type of instance (eg `t2.large`). When an instance is Stopped (which is required to change Instance Type), there is no host being used, so there is no underlying host.

Comment: @krishna_mee2004, I was able to create new t2.xlarge on the same AZ.

Comment: @John Rotenstein, the list is not empty. All type were listed (m, c, r, d, i) excepted "T" ...
Image was build from a marketplace AMI but I create a new one with the same configuration... on a t2.xlarge wihtout any problem :)

I finally created an AMI of my instances and redeployed them on a t2.xlarge, but it could be interesting to find why it was not possible on existing instances.
And new instances (next to image creation and redeployment) are able to change type for "t" types...

Comment: Oh! Yes, Marketplace offerings can be restricted by instance type. That was the cause.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein 
I was wrong, this instance was not created with the marketplace!
It was just a windows 2016 Base (3 EBS drives, 1EIP, 2 Networks interfaces... and that's all!)
Definitvely, I don't understand why I cannot see T type in the drop-list...

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Found : it was a placement group configuration !

Comment: Oh! T2's don't qualify for placement groups. Excellent!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a placement group configuration issue!

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/general-purpose-instances.html?shortFooter=true#general-purpose-features